# How to validate the request body for various attacks?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-security, hibernate-validator

I am writing a **spring-boot** rest api.

Is there any better way to **validate** fields in the **request body** such that it should not contain anything which could lead to any kind of attack defined by **OWASP**.

**My Approach** : Currently using javax-validations @Pattern annotation.

```
public class Request {

    @JsonProperty(value = "name")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\\s]*[a-zA-Z]$", message = "invalid name value")
    private String name;
}
```

So if we pass **json** like:

```
{
    name : "<script>alert(1)<script>"
}
```

This will get rejected when **RequestBody** gets **validated**.

Is this the correct way to do server-side validation to protect from attacks like blind XSS and second-order SQL and Cross-Site Scripting.

Comment: correct? in accordance to what? what is correct is an opinion. There are recommendations, OWASP for instance, this question is opinion based https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet.html

Comment: @Toerktumlare, what I want to say is, could this approach be considered a right way to filter the values such that it should not contain any bad data which could possibly be executed as script/sql statement in the backend and thus leads to an attack.

Comment: How to provide the sanitization of data and the perform business level validations on it.

Comment: I provided a link, it has all the information you need start reading

Answer (score -1):

We need to analyze how SQL injection happens and how XSS happens.

- For SQL injection,  we'd better restrict the input parameters for the SQL operation. Restrict the user to append or reconstruct invalid values to construct the executing SQL.
  An example is:
  [1]: https://github.com/iihero/blog/blob/main/securityprj/src/main/java/com/sean/workshop/security/ids/SQLInjection.java
- For XSS, the most important part is to validate and restrict the response part.  Analyze the response content and avoid the XSS value.
  In your example,  if you don't output the content of the source: "alert(1)" directly.  It will not have impact.

Comment: but we also don't want to save data into DBs containing alert(1) inside script tag.

Comment: This should be another topic.  If you don't want to save this content,  you need do the validation before the persisting.  From this point of view, you are right. It depends on the real requirement.   Imagine, some customers happen to want to save such a content but don't want to be XSS attacked.